# How to replace a symbolic link with a copy of a file it links to?

Tags: command-line, files, symlink, cp

Having a (single, no batch filesystem processing needed) symlink, what a command line to use to replace it with a copy of the file it links to?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
cp --remove-destination "$(readlink <symlink>)" <symlink>
```

Comment: error "-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'" when executed from a debian environment.

Comment: If `<symlink>` is a symlink to a relative path, that only works if the `<symlink>` is in the current directory. You may want to use `readlink -f`. Or if using `zsh`: `cp --remove-destination path/to/symlink(:A) path/to/symlink`

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
file=path/to/symlink
{ rm -f -- "$file" && cat > "$file"; } < "$file"
```

(that only copies the content, not the file's metadata like permissions and ownership).